# setting up Eclim to support PHP

Tags: vim, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have the plugin PDT installed with my Eclim using:

```
DISPLAY=:1 ./eclipse/eclipse -nosplash -consolelog -debug \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
  -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios \
  -installIU org.eclipse.php.feature.group
```

I compiled the thing using dargs for PHP:

```
ant -Declipse.home=/home/tipu/downloads/eclipse -Dplugins=php
```

Creating a project gives me:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find nature for 
alias 'php'.  Supported aliases include: javascript=org.eclipse.
wst.jsdt.core.jsNature, java=org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature
while executing command (port: 9091): -editor vim -command project_create 
-f "/home/tipu/phpproj2/" -n php
```

Thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg please take a look on this one.

Answer (score 0):

problem was that my eclipse was of the indigo release and installed the pdt from the hellios repository. they must both match, and that wasn't the case between hellios and indigo.